# Display Image based on DataGridView selection throws an error

Tags: c#, image, search, gridview

I am using C# and in my Form, I have DataGridView with 18 columns. Column 18 is the one that holds the image. I also have search box to filter by Model Name and I have Image Box that would display the picture based on my GridView selection. 
Here is my code to display the image:

```
//GET THE IMAGE INTO THE IMAGE BOX BASED ON GRIDVIEW SELECTION
    private void DGV_FEATURE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] img = (byte[])DGV_FEATURE.CurrentRow.Cells[18].Value;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);

        PB_IMAGE.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
```

So far so good... When I select any GridView row, I have image displayed in my PB_Image box. The issue happens when I search for any particular Model name to filter down my list. Now if I select row from the GridView, I get this error:
[GridView error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14h1I.jpg)

Can anyone spot what is wrong with my code and how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
Always __TAG__ your question correctly! Also : __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! - Also: What is unclear about the error and why not use the debugger??

Comment: You have 18. Does the index starts with 0. that would be 0-17? 18 does not exist if that's the case.

Comment: @ jmag... Thank you. This helped :-). I had to modify my stored procedure that I call when searching for model names